# JAVA/SAX - Loss of characters using XML Parser

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I'm using **SAX Parser** to parse the XML file of RSS feeds on an Android App and sometimes the parsing of the pubDate of an item isn't completed (incomplete characters).

**Ex:**

**Actual PubDate** Thu, 02 Apr 2015 12:23:41 +0000

**PubDate Result of the parse:** Thu,

Here is the code that I'm using in the parser handler:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if ("item".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            currentItem = new RssItem(url);
        } else if ("title".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            parsingTitle = true;
        } else if ("link".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            parsingLink = true;
        } else if ("pubDate".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            parsingDate = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if ("item".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            rssItems.add(currentItem);
            currentItem = null;
        } else if ("title".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            parsingTitle = false;
        } else if ("link".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            parsingLink = false;
        } else if ("pubDate".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            parsingDate = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if (parsingTitle) {
            if (currentItem != null) {
                currentItem.setTitle(new String(ch, start, length));
                parsingTitle = false;
            }
        } else if (parsingLink) {
            if (currentItem != null) {
                currentItem.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
                parsingLink = false;
            }
        } else if (parsingDate) {
            if (currentItem != null) {
                currentItem.setDate(new String(ch, start, length));
                parsingDate = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The loss of characters is pretty random, it happens in different XML items every time I run the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that there is exactly one `characters()` call per element. That is not a safe assumption. Build up your string over 1+ calls to `characters()`, then apply it in `endElement()`.

Or, better yet, use any one of [a number of existing RSS parser libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=rss).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up following the advice on the string builder, it worked!